# Disable CTRL-D from closing my window with the terminator terminal emulator)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I am often logged in several SSH sessions at once. To logout from several sessions, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, until I am back on my local machine.

However, I occasionally press it once too many, and my terminal exits.

Is there a way to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> unable to close my terminal ?

I am using terminator as my terminal emulator.

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1243138/why-does-ignoreeof-not-work-in-zsh) for Zsh.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can also disable eof generally in bash:

`set -o ignoreeof`

Comment: But if you do that indiscriminately, it'll apply when logged in over ssh as well.

Comment: I'm using terminator 0.97. When I do set -o ignoreeof, it blocks ctrl-d (doesn't exit) 10 times with a message:  Use "exit" to leave the shell. On the 11th ctrl-d, it exits.

Comment: OMG, thank you!! That (accidental terminal cloures) was a huge annoyance for me. Added to ~/.bashrc; works in konsole | xfce4-terminal | ... :-D

Comment: @Gilles Good input, do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 43):

You can use the `IGNOREEOF` environment variable in bash. So `export IGNOREEOF=42` and you'll have to press `Ctrl+D` forty-two times before it actually quits your shell.

POSIX `set` has an `-o ignoreeof` setting too.

Comment: Forty-three times: the first forty-two are ignored, and the last one actually quits. :-)

Comment: I figured Forty-three times would be too redundant. Definately the `set -o ignoreeof` would be more practical

Comment: But if you do that indiscriminately, it'll apply when logged in over ssh as well.

Comment: But you have to write the command every time you open a terminal.How do you disable this permanently?

Comment: @MycrofD Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: I almost upvoted, then noticed the karma was 42

Answer (score 2):

The Ctrl-D EOF character is being interpreted by the shell, rather than the terminal emulator specifically. Other answers have covered bash settings, although other shells are different.

For C-shells (e.g. tcsh) you can add it to your tcshrc file:

```
# Prevent accidental logouts completely
set ignoreeof
# Just prevent the first two, and allow the third
set ignoreeof=3
```

For fish shell, the Ctrl-D behaviour is controlled by the keybinding. The default setting is `delete-or-exit`, so you can set the keybinding for `\cd` to `delete-char` to only support delete.

More details are in the [Fish Github issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5593) (e.g. in versions before 3.0 you need to add the `bind` to a function called `fish_user_key_bindings`, after 3.0 you can put it into `~/.config/fish/config.fish`) but in summary:

```
bind \cd delete-char  # Don't exit on accidental Ctrl-D
bind \cd\cd\cd delete-or-exit  # Exit on the third one
```