# command to log the current user out of the system?

Tags: shell, command-line, users

I often use `reboot -n` and `shutdown -t now` commands to restart and shutdown my system.

Is there something similar to log out of the current user account?

*That is logout of my user session for the whole session. I'm using Ubuntu server with i3 so maybe I'm looking for an Ubuntu specific answer(?)*

Comment: but what if you're running ksh or zsh or tcsh? (tongue-in-cheek)

Comment: @jeffschaller :p maybe I should be, I don't know much about zsh but I seem to see it mentioned in a lot of places :-)

Comment: just (indirectly) pointing out that while bash is a common shell, it's not your Everything -- it has some built-in commands, but reboot and shutdown are not bash commands.

Comment: @JeffSchaller interesting I didn't realize that. What exactly counts as standard bash is it the commands available on all posix systems?

Comment: see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) in regards to "Shell Builtin Commands"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logout` is used by users to end their own session

Comment: I get back "bash: logout: not login shell: use `exit'"

Comment: `exit` will exit you from the shell you are in, `logout` will log you out if you are in a login shell

Comment: I get the same error as @Phi - did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have default shellopts i.e `ignoreeof` is false. On a blank line <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will exit you out of login shells and ssh sessions.

Comment: Not if `ignoreeof` has been set.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139115/disable-ctrl-d-window-close-in-terminator-terminal-emulator